# Setting Data Validation Rule via Script Sets Incorrect Relativity

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following function:

```
function FixDataValidation() {
  var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('SkillData')
  dataSheet.getRange('E2:E213').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .setAllowInvalid(false)
  .requireValueInRange(spreadsheet.getRange('SkillData!$P2:$U2'), true)
  .build());
};
```

However, after it runs, it sets the validation range to 'SkillData!$P$2:$U$2'.  Obviously, this breaks, since it makes every row reference the same range, instead of relative ranges.  But I've triple-checked (including a direct paste of the function), and the function is not putting dollar signs in front of the row numbers.  What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need different rules for each row.

```js
function FixDataValidation() {
  const dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('SkillData');
  const rules = [];
  for (let i = 2; i <= 213; i++) {
    const range = dataSheet.getRange(`P${i}:U${i}`);
    const rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
        .setAllowInvalid(false)
        .requireValueInRange(range)
        .build();
    rules.push([rule]);
  }
  dataSheet.getRange('E2:E213').setDataValidations(rules);
};
```